# xampp - mysql #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-error-1045

So i have gotten this error a couple times. Tried different things to solve it, but the solution continues to illude me. So far the only way i have managed to regain access to my local sql server is to remove the xampp installation, and reinstall it.

After reinstall i am able to access the mysql database no problems.

It would seem how ever, either after restarting the computer, or the new day, 
This error comes up again.

At first, i was just using the root account with no password, config settings to match this,
and i would get the same error except it would say 'using password: NO'

i then uninstalled and reinstalled xampp and set a passsword to the root account. this worked fine the entire working day. I come back on monday, and try to access my local database,
i get, #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Seeing as i cannot afford to continue to reinstalled every day, it would be greate if i could find a solution to this.

edit:
I forgot to mention i get the same error trying to access the mysql database through command prompt.

Comment: In general, it's best to create a new database user for your web application. Just give this user permissions just on the database associated with the website. You do not want the root password to fall into the wrong hands. But I do not know why you are getting the problems accessing the database with the root user though.

Comment: the local database is only ever used by myself. we have a dedicated server for our live stuff, but i use the local database to comb through backups, and private developement.

Answer (score 0):

This was my own doing.
I run off mysql backups. Every time i import the backup, i import and override the mysql.user fields as well.